# Sort community lists in the order which I use them the most

Tags: feature-request, communities-list

When dropping down the community list in the upper-left corner of the site, it would be nice to see all communities I've ever posted in sorted to the top and in descending order according to my frequency of activity.

For example, I rarely post on Graphic Design, but the few posts I have made there suggest that I have at least *some* interest in the topic, so it's likely that I will return there again in the future.  Having it at least at the bottom of the top would be nice.  The list currently does appear to sort to the top my most heavily used communities for which I have a few thousand rep apiece, but the ones I rarely visit are tossed into the mix of the ones I never visit.

Comment: FYI, You can customize the list by clicking "edit", and arrange / add / remove  them however you want.

Comment: @JonasCz Ah, you're right!  I guess I never thought of that because the implicit behavior of auto-adding my most heavily used communities gave me reason to assume my lesser-used were being excluded due to the minimal activity.